# update query throws exception in python

Tags: python, mysql, sql

My requirement is to change the name field to sun if id is 1.Below is my code.It throws exception and print error in update?.Is i am doing anything wrong on query or python code?

```
     import MySQLdb
     import datetime    
        a="sun"
        b=1
        sql="update selva set name=%s where selid=%d"
        try:
            cursor.execute(sql,[a,b])
            db.commit()
        except:
            print "error in update"
            db.rollback()

        db.close()
```

Any Help will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Did you try reraising the exception so you can see what it is?

Comment: i am newbie to python,i found out the exception throws by using print in except block,even i don't know which type of exception throws in my code

Comment: Then don't catch it! Remove the try/except and let Python report the exception to you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The placeholders in the query should be `%s`, not `%d`. I have modified your exception handler to catch and print the exception, and to close the database connection in a `finally` clause to ensure that it will always be closed.

```
import MySQLdb
import datetime    
a="sun"
b=1
sql="update selva set name=%s where selid=%s"
try:
    cursor.execute(sql, [a, b])
    db.commit()
except Exception, exc:
    print "error in update"
    print "Exception : %s" % exc
    db.rollback()
finally:
    db.close()
```

Comment: please use tuple rather list.

Comment: @sundarnatarajСундар : tuple or list or any other sequence is fine.

Comment: i think for sql we use tuple since they are immutable . even query result are tuples.so it is good practice.please correct me if i am wrong:)

Comment: i am getting error near %s since there are no quotes.

Comment: The data type of the query result has no bearing on the data type used in `cursor.execute`. Any sequence is permitted, although a tuple would seem to be the defacto standard.

Comment: There should not be quotes around the `%s` - you must be doing something else wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
 import MySQLdb
 import datetime    
    a="sun"
    b=1
    sql="update selva set name = '%s' where selid = '%d'"
    cmd = sql % (a, b)
    try:
        cursor.execute(cmd)
        db.commit()
    except Exception, e:
        print "error in update"
        print repr(e)
        db.rollback()

    db.close()
```

Tell if there is error message printed out.

Comment: @Madhesh What about adding some spaces beside equals. I've update my answer.

Comment: You don't want to do it this way which forms the query via string interpolation. Instead you want to use parameterised queries as already present in the OP. The reason: string interpolation is vulnerable to SQL injection attacks whereas parameterised queries are not. Anyway, you need to put single quotes around the `name`.

Comment: error in update
OperationalError(1054, "Unknown column 'sun' in 'field list'")

Comment: @Madhesh That means you don't have a column named sun, do you?

Comment: @mhawke,after putting single quotes in %s,my query works,thanks for help me.

Comment: @m170897017,i put '%s' instead of %s in your answer.my code executes now.please change that line.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `execute` invocation like this

```
cursor.execute ("update selva set name=%s where selid=%s", (a,b)) #passing a tuple with parameters
```

or

```
cursor.execute ("update selva set name='%s' where selid=%d" % (a,b)) #passing a raw sql command with interpoled data
```